# MIME RFC "Content-Type" parameter confusion? Unclear RFC specification

Tags: mime, specifications, rfc, rfc822

I'm trying to implement a basic MIME parser for the `multipart/related` in C++/Qt.

So far I've been writing some basic parser code for headers, and I'm reading the RFCs to get an idea how to do everything as close to the specification as possible. Unfortunately there is a part in the RFC that confuses me a bit:

From [RFC882](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) Section 3.1.1:

> Each header field can be viewed as a single, logical  line  of
> ASCII  characters,  comprising  a field-name and a field-body.
> For convenience, the field-body  portion  of  this  conceptual
> entity  can be split into a multiple-line representation; this
> is called "folding".  The general rule is that wherever  there
> may  be  linear-white-space  (NOT  simply  LWSP-chars), a CRLF
> immediately followed by AT LEAST one LWSP-char may instead  be
> inserted.  Thus, the single line

Alright, so I simply parse a header field and if a CRLF follows with linear whitespace, I simply concat those in a useful manner to result in a single header line. Let's proceed...

From [RFC2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5.1) Section 5.1:

> In the Augmented BNF notation of RFC 822, a Content-Type header field
> value is defined as follows:

```
 content := "Content-Type" ":" type "/" subtype
            *(";" parameter)
            ; Matching of media type and subtype
            ; is ALWAYS case-insensitive.
```

> [...]

```
 parameter := attribute "=" value
```

> 

```
 attribute := token
              ; Matching of attributes
              ; is ALWAYS case-insensitive.
```

> 

```
 value := token / quoted-string
```

> 

```
 token := 1*<any (US-ASCII) CHAR except SPACE, CTLs,
             or tspecials>
```

Okay. So it seems if you want to specify a `Content-Type` header with parameters, simply do it like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; foo=bar; something=else
```

... and a folded version of the same header would look like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    foo=bar;
    something=else
```

Correct? Good. As I kept reading the RFCs, I came across the following in [RFC2387](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387) Section 5.1 (Examples):

```
 Content-Type: Multipart/Related; boundary=example-1
         start="<950120.aaCC@XIson.com>";
         type="Application/X-FixedRecord"
         start-info="-o ps"

 --example-1
 Content-Type: Application/X-FixedRecord
 Content-ID: <950120.aaCC@XIson.com>

 [data]
 --example-1
 Content-Type: Application/octet-stream
 Content-Description: The fixed length records
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 Content-ID: <950120.aaCB@XIson.com>

 [data]

 --example-1--
```

Hmm, this is odd. Do you see the `Content-Type` header? It has a number of parameters, but not all have a ";" as parameter delimiter.

Maybe I just didn't read the RFCs correctly, but if my parser works strictly like the specification defines, the `type` and `start-info` parameters would result in a single string or worse, a parser error.

Guys, what's your thought on this? Just a typo in the RFCs? Or did I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: When working with such standards, you should always be tolerant when reading the input and strict when writing the output.

Comment: It is a typo in the examples.  Parameters must always be delimited with semicolons correctly, even when folded.  The folding is not meant to change the semantics of a header, only to allow for readability and to account for systems that have line length restrictions.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Why don't you post it as answer so I can accept it? I tried to contact the original author of the RFC, but they didn't respond so far.

Comment: Great question, I had the same "*Wait, what?*" experience reading through 1521 and 2045.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a typo in the examples. Parameters must always be delimited with semicolons correctly, even when folded. The folding is not meant to change the semantics of a header, only to allow for readability and to account for systems that have line length restrictions.

Comment: Absolutely a typo.  Here's the BNF:  `content := "Content-Type" ":" type "/" subtype *(";" parameter)`.  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly a typo, but in general (and from experience) you should be able to handle this kind of thing "in the wild" as well. In particular, mail clients vary *wildly* in their ability to generate valid messages and follow all of the relevant specifications (if anything, it's even worse in the email/SMTP world than it is the WWW world!)

Comment: I only have a handle MIME data from a handful of systems and most of them produce valid MIME structures. But I'm considering to release my MIME parser under the GPL or BSD license so everyone else can use it, too.